# while downloading image from server how to set a progess bar/process indicator

Tags: java-me

I am downloading images in my **j2me** application from server.

I want t show a progress bar or activity indicator until my downloading is not finished.

But I don't know how to do this? I searched about it but didn't get the answer.

Comment: show the code snippet of your current user interface. also, consider studying tutorial **Networking, User Experience, and Threads** referred to at [lcdui tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/lcdui/info). _"examples that illustrate multithreaded networking and the use of a wait screen..."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to user Gauge Control for your requirement. Create a simple for with Gauge Control and display that form before starting the downloading code.

```
// first display progressbar form
ProgressForm progressForm = new ProgressForm ( "Please wait" ); 
display.setCurrent(progressForm); 

// now downloading code in background
new Thread ( new Runnable() 
{
      public void run()
      {
          // Image downloading code goes here
      }
}).start();
```